# How attach CJuiDatePicker in Yii to hidden field and show calendar on the click by link?

Tags: php, yii

I have a form, i needs attach CJuiDatePicker.
CJuiDatePicker has `flat` option, but if it's `true`, calendar shows inline.
I am want show calendar by the click to link for example, and manipulate values from CJuiDatePicker after value in calendar checked.
It's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set CJuiDatePicker flat option on true, and hide it in div with id="HiddenCalendar".

```
<div id="hiddenCalendar" style="display:none">
  <?php echo $this->widget('zii.widgets.CJuiDatePicker', array('flat'=>true)); ?>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <a href="javascript:$('#hiddenCalendar').toggle();">Show Calendar</a>
</div>
```

Comment: @AndreyVorobyev try `visibility` instead `display:none`

Comment: @AndreyVorobyev, I try on my form - it's perfect hide and show by click, check your CJuiDatePicker's div style